# Unable to add scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I get this error while adding a functionality to my web app.
-> so basically there are a few cards on the map and if user 'click' any of the one, the app will scroll to description of that particular card.

And I suppose the error `[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 136ms` is coming from the following code

```
const PlaceDetails = ({ place, selected, refProp }) => {
  // console.log(place);

  const classes = useStyles();


  if (selected)
    refProp?.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });

  return (
    <Card elevation={6}>
      <CardMedia
...
```

map.jsx

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
        // get key from https://console.cloud.google.com/
        defaultCenter={coordinates}
        center={coordinates}
        defaultZoom={14}
        margin={[50, 50, 50, 50]}
        options={""}
        onChange={(e) => {
          // console.log(e);
          setCoordinates({ lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng });
          setBounds({ ne: e.marginBounds.ne, sw: e.marginBounds.sw });
        }}
        // as we click a child (card) we want information about which child was the click from the map component all the way to the list component
        onChildClick={(child) => setChildClicked(child)}
      >
        {places?.map((place, i) => (
          <div
            className={classes.markerContainer}
            lat={Number(place?.latitude)}
            lng={Number(place?.longitude)}
            key={i}
          >
```

List.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createRef } from "react";

import {
  CircularProgress,
  Grid,
  Typography,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Select,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import PlaceDetails from "../PlaceDetails/PlaceDetails";

import useStyles from "./styles";

const List = ({ places, childClicked, isLoading }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [type, setType] = useState("restaurants");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");
  const [elRefs, setElRefs] = useState([]);

  // console.log({ places });

  useEffect(() => {
    const refs = Array(places?.length)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => elRefs[i] || createRef());

    setElRefs(refs);
  }, [places]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      
      {isLoading ? (
        <div className={classes.loading}>
          <CircularProgress size="5rem" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>
          // ... other code
          <Grid container spacing={3} className={classes.list}>
            {places?.map((place, i) => (
              <Grid item key={i} xs={12}>
                <PlaceDetails
                  place={place}
                  selected={Number(childClicked) === i}
                  refProp={elRefs[i]}
                />
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

could somebody help me in understanding why the scroll is not working and what error chrome consoles is showing me.

Comment: [Take a look at the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5BViolation%5D++handler+took+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan I am sorry but I didn't get that

Comment: Click the link and find a relevant answer

Comment: Thx ! although my doubt was not that i was getting this error message, rather i was unable to get the scrollToView() work. And somehow i thought the error was related to that.

Comment: So please change the title of the question